# Auth JWT example PHP

Tags: docusignapi

Using https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-php-jwt

I haven't successfully implemented the above repository for JWT authentication, I have the return:

```
C O N S E N T R E Q U I R E D
Ask the user who will be impersonated to run the following url:
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx&redirect_uri=https://www.docusign.com
It will ask the user to login and to approve access by your application.

Alternatively, an Administrator can use Organization Administration to
pre-approve one or more users.
```

When accessing the informed URL I cannot login, it says that the credentials are invalid.

Yes I have a demo account, I am accessing it with login and password in another tab, this is all right.

But in my integration it generates the message and I can't proceed, I'm trying to generate the token for access. The integration is all completed, I developed it with the token generator available (developers.docusign.com/oauth-token-generator), it is just missing that part of JWT authentication that is causing me problems

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're not able to log in to the Demo environment, you'll likely need to do a Password Reset using the `Forgot Password` link on the login page. Do keep in mind that while you can sign up for a Demo account using the same email address as a Prod account, those two accounts will have separate passwords, so be careful to track of which environment you're taking action in.

If you don't have a Demo/Sandbox account at all, they're freely available from the DocuSign Developer Center: https://developers.docusign.com/ > Click 'Create Sandbox'

Comment: Yes I have a demo account, I am accessing it with login and password in another tab, this is all right.

But in my integration it generates the message and I can't proceed, I'm trying to generate the token for access.

The integration is all completed, I developed it with the token generator available (https://developers.docusign.com/oauth-token-generator), it is just missing that part of JWT authentication that is causing me problems.

Comment: In that case, I'd recommend opening a case with DocuSign Support: support.docusign.com/
You might try logging out of the alternate tab, or clearing your browser cache/cookies.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying the URL provided by the example in an incognito browser window. Normally there is no problem using a regular browser window for this one-time step.

The consent url simply enables you to login via the in-person OAuth Authorization Code flow. You authenticate and then grant consent.